# Move all instances of a character to the end of the string

Tags: ruby

If I havd a string like:

```
"Hi! Hi! Hi!"
```

How can I move the exclamation marks to the end of the string.

Expected output:

```
"Hi Hi Hi!!!"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: Please add examples of what the output should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with:

```
s = "Hi! Hi! Hi!"
s1 = s.delete("!")+s.scan("!").join
```

- .delete("!") just returns a string without "!".
- .scan("!") collects all "!" from a string.
- .join just joins all elements of an array to a string

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you could sort the characters by their index, except when the character is `!` :

```
"Hi! Hi! Hi!".each_char.sort_by.with_index{ |c, i| c == '!' ? Float::INFINITY : i }.join
#=> "Hi Hi Hi!!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
str.tr('!','') + '!'*str.count('!')
 #=> "Hi Hi Hi!!!"
```